# Silverlight textbox conditional binding with style

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am binding an int to a textbox. Is there a way to change the color of the textbox based on the binded value?

For eg. if the int if > 0, the textbox should be green, else, red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you would use Value Converters, one that converters from an int to a color. You then bind the background property to the int property (as well as binding the text).

Here's an post about them [So What’s a Silverlight Value Converter Anyway?](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx)

Comment: I think this is a must to know thing for any silverlight developer, because this is equivalent to if-else condition thing. Thanks a ton for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get more complex and use proper Styles, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410579/binding-for-wpf-styles/6149455#6149455).