# How to resolve BindingExpression path errors in Debug Output that don't affect the WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My application runs and renders correctly but I have noticed numerous errors in my debug output when the Window is loading.  It's the same 3 errors for each item in an Itemscontrol which adds up to 100's.

The Itemscontrol DataTemplate has a Path object which has its DataContext bound to a property that is passed through an IValueConverter that returns an anonymous type which attributes on that Path Object bind to.

```
<Path Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,1,2,1" StrokeThickness="2"
      DataContext="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ShapeConverter},
                            IsAsync=True}" >
    <Path.Data>
        <Binding Path="Data" IsAsync="True" />
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Fill>
        <Binding Path="Fill" IsAsync="True" />
    </Path.Fill>
    <Path.Stroke>
        <Binding Path="Stroke" IsAsync="True" />
    </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

ShapeConverter is an IValueConverter that returns an anonymous type to bind to.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int status = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        var geometry = CreateShapeGeometry(status);
        var strokecolor = GetStrokeColor(status);
        var fillcolor = GetFillColor(status);

        return new
        {
            Data = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(geometry).ToString(),
            Stroke = strokecolor,
            Fill = fillcolor
        };
    }
```

I understand what the errors mean, as the properties it is looking for do not exist on Alarm, they exist on the Anonymous Type which it resolves and renders correctly.

What I don't understand is how to resolve BindingExpression path errors that aren't really errors.  I am also wondering if this causing the screen to load somewhat slowly.

Here are the errors:

> (Summary)
>   BindingExpression path error:  'Fill', 'Stroke', 'Data' property not found on object Alarm.
>
> (Actual)
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Fill' property not found on 'object' ''Alarm' (HashCode=37465686)'. BindingExpression:Path=Fill; DataItem='Alarm' (HashCode=37465686); target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Fill' (type 'Brush')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Stroke' property not found on 'object' ''Alarm' (HashCode=37465686)'. BindingExpression:Path=Stroke; DataItem='Alarm' (HashCode=37465686); target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Stroke' (type 'Brush')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Data' property not found on 'object' ''Alarm' (HashCode=37465686)'. BindingExpression:Path=Data; DataItem='Alarm' (HashCode=37465686); target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Data' (type 'Geometry')

After some tinkering I'm not sure that this problem has anything to do with Anonymous types.  I changed the convert method as follows but it didnt change my output.

```
 public class Foo
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Stroke { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Fill { get; set;  }
}
```

Convert Method

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int status = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        var geometry = CreateShapeGeometry(status);
        var strokecolor = GetStrokeColor(status);
        var fillcolor = GetFillColor(status);

        Foo f = new Foo { Data = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(geometry).ToString(), Stroke = strokecolor, Fill = fillcolor };

        return f;
    }
```

Comment: the slowdown will only happen in DEBUG mode, in release mode there will be virtually no performance impact due to the errors

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Are they actual errors I need to be concerned about at all?  Is there a surpress tag for them at all?  I'm just preparing for the possiblity of having to explain them to a build manager.

Comment: The question is why an `Alarm` object is the `DataContext` at any point, if you can avoid that you will not get any errors.

Comment: @H.B.  I thought perhaps it was getting it from the DataTemplate declaration.  <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type m:Alarm}" > but even after I took out the DataType attribute the message is the same.

Comment: @jrandomuser: `DataType` only matters if you do not set the `x:Key` (which then uses type based implicit application). By the way, you could use the attribute notation for those three property bindings (e.g. `Data="{Binding Data}"`), also: Using `IsAsync` there is pointless as all three properties are instantly accessible as soon as the converter code returns.

Comment: @H.B. removed the IsAsync's and the DataType declaration and changed the binding to inline attributes.  Its definately cleaner but it didn't help to clean up the output errors.  I also tried adding BindsDirectlyToSource=False hoping maybe it would force it to stop trying to resolve the Bindings to properties on the source object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that while you can create and bind to properties on an anonymous type or even an instance of a defined class that are returned from a Value Converter, as it goes to do the binding it will encounter but overcome debug errors.

Another approach in this case was to create a set of styles instead as static resources and then bind the Style Attribute of the Path object.  See [Binding for WPF Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410579/binding-for-wpf-styles)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resource out there that talk about binding errors can reduce app performance.

See number 7 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2-performance-tuning.aspx

Comment: Sorta but all this does is control what level the issues show up in your output.  I know what they are, just not why they are or how to resolve them.

Comment: why use an anonymous at all, why not bind the 'Value' property to each of the Path.Data, Path.Fill & Path.Stroke each with it's own converter. Personally I would try and remove the use of a converter all together.

Comment: I had done the translation here because the ViewModel itself doesn't have any concept of Shape or Color etc.  All that the ViewModel is aware of is that it has an alarm with a status of X.  I could move a lot of this to the ViewModel but so much of the View is determined by status that if I created bindable properties on the VM I would have dozens.  I would have to make one for Border color, background color, associated storyboard, font weight, text color, parent border color etc...

Comment: I'm not suggesting putting these properties on the VM, I'm suggesting a converter for each way you want to 'convert' the Value property

Comment: I see.  I had that before and thought maybe it'd be better to group ones that apply to a single element together.  I may have to break them back out.  I was starting to think it was an issue with requiring Full Trust to correctly bind anonymous types but after a recent test I dont think it has anything to do with Anonymous Types at all.  Im updating the question with what I found.

Comment: I had a thought.  Since there are a finite number of shapes I'm rendering I'm going to try to declare a bunch of styles and then just dynamically set that instead.