# Bind Style-Resource to StackPanel items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a a Style-Resource which is defined in the local ResourceDictionary of a UserControl to all items in a StackPanel.
The ItemSource of the StackPanel is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Button>` in the ViewModel.

Thus, the aim is to bind the Style-Resource to the Style-Property of these Buttons.

The following simplified approach results in this error:

> ArgumentException: Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.

MyViewModel.cs:

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
        public ObservableCollection<Button> MyButtons { get; private set; }
 }
```

MyView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=MyViewModel}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="StyleStackPanelButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource StyleStackPanelButton}" />
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource StyleStackPanelButton}" />
     </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

---

I've also tried to use a Converter as suggested here
[Binding for WPF Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410579/binding-for-wpf-styles)
as follows:

```
...
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonExtensions}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Setter Property="Style">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StyleConverter}">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource StyleStackPanelButton}" />
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
...
```

This results in the same error:

> ArgumentException: Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.

---

Is there a any other way to bind a lcoal Style-Resource to a Setter-Property of an Item in a Stackpanel-ItemSource?

Comment: "*an ObservableCollection<Button> in the ViewModel*" is probably the root cause of your trouble. A view model must not contain view elements. The Buttons should instead be created by a DataTemplate that is used as the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens 
You are completely right. I don't like it either. The problem is that this design can not be changed due to some architectural restrictions.  
The buttons are injected via DI by another component for which I am not responsible. The whole logic of the buttons is supposed to be carried by another team. 
My task is only to hook these buttons into the frontend and adapt the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding Buttons directly to the ItemsSource collection, it is sufficient to assign the Button Style to the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StyleStackPanelButton}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

Alternatively, declare a default Button Style - without `x:Key` - in the StackPanel Resources:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Button"
                           BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleStackPanelButton}"/>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```